# using fileinfo instead of string

Tags: filestream, fileinfo

i have this code below:

```
private void encryptFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                bool asciiArmor = false;
                bool withIntegrityCheck = false;
                pgp.EncryptFile(@attachmentTextBox.Text,
                         @"C:\TCkeyPublic.txt",
                         @"C:\OUTPUT.pgp",
                         asciiArmor,
                         withIntegrityCheck);
                MessageBox.Show("File Encrypted Successfully!");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File Encryption Fail!");
            }            
        }
```

I want to change `@"C:\TCkeyPublic.txt"` into something like `new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName)`. So user don't have to always change the code when they have a different file name or file path.

But when i try to do that, there is this red zizag line under the code and when i put my mouse over, it says that it cannot convert System.IO.FileInfo to System.IO.Stream.

```
                        try
                        {
                            bool asciiArmor = false;
                            bool withIntegrityCheck = false;
                            pgp.EncryptFile(@attachmentTextBox.Text,
                                     new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName),
                                     @"C:\OUTPUT.pgp",
                                     asciiArmor,
                                     withIntegrityCheck);
                            MessageBox.Show("File Encrypted Successfully!");
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("File Encryption Fail!");
                        }
```

i am using didisoft pgp(BouncyCastle.CryptoExt.dll and DidiSoft.Pgp.dll) to build my project for using PGP for encrypting files using a PGP public key and decrypt it using a passphrase and a private key.

Kindly Advice!!! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
using System.IO;
...
using (var inputStream = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var outputStream = new FileStream(@"C:\OUTPUT.pgp", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
   pgp.EncryptFile(@attachmentTextBox.Text, inputStream, outputStream, ..
}
```

Don't have your didisoft so can't verify this myself..

Comment: now i am getting i am able to debug the program and run normally but when i click on my encrypt button, there is an error on 'using (var inputStream = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open))' 

When i use F11 on my program, this happens: _A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Tian Ci\Desktop\fdasfdafda.txt' because it is being used by another process._

Comment: @user2930173 you need to know which process blocks the file and remove this block (for example by killing this process). There is a number of utilities that can do this, for example - Handle from SysInternals: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655

Comment: I've updated the answer now this lock should not prevent reading

Comment: After trying the new answer, there is no file dialog box opened when i click the encrypt button. Meaning i cannot choose my public key to encrypt my files. Does FileStream open a dialogbox? Really apologize for the trouble. I am not a programming student whatsoever. i learnt really basic programming language.

Comment: no filestream does not open the dialog. You need to open it separately. Basically, you can test filestream with hard-coded file name (like @"C:\TCkeyPublic.txt" in your 1st example) and then find out what is wrong with file dialog, because actually it is not related to original question

Answer (score 0):

The file locking occurs because the EncryptFile method from the DidiSoft API also tries to obtain a stream from the same file. Probably the example snippet bellow is what you intend to do:

```
bool asciiArmor = false;
bool withIntegrityCheck = false;
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{
  pgp.EncryptFile(@attachmentTextBox.Text,
                  openFileDialog1.FileName,
                  @"C:\OUTPUT.pgp",
                  asciiArmor,
                  withIntegrityCheck);
}
```

If you prefer to work with streams you can check the EncryptStream method as illustrated in 
http://www.didisoft.com/net-openpgp/examples/encrypt-file/#EncryptStream

By the way you are welcome to contact us directly at support@didisoft.com